# Does the combination of the Follow-up Shot infusion and Dual Kinetic Control utility wild talent with Telekinetic Blast use a total of 4 projectiles?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

Does the combination of the [Follow-up Shot](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/infusion-wild-talents#toc9) infusion and [Dual Kinetic Control](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/aether-utility-talents#toc11) utility wild talent with [Telekinetic Blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/kineticist-elements/#Telekinetic_Blast) use a total of 4 projectiles, and does the projectiles affect the same initial target or can target another creature?

Comment: You may want to quote what those abilities do for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 2):

### You can "blast" *up to* 4 objects (in pairs) at *up to* 2 targets.

Telekinetic Blast allows you to wield one unattended object at one target.

Dual Kinetic Control allows you to do the same amount of damage with two objects.

Follow-up Shot allows you to repeat this, but makes no requirements that it be against the same target. Your damage for this second attack is (most likely) reduced.

Comment: Can this combo with Foe Throw Infusion let you a similar have the effect of the Many Throw Infusion but at an earlier level? If you can pick and throw an enemy with Foe Throw then you technically can pick up up to 4 enemies with this combination right?

Comment: That would be another question, but the answer is simple. You can't use Foe Throw and Follow Up at the same time because they're both form infusions.